# Comando "TRIM" SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou trabalhando com `Sql Server`, e preciso fazer um `trim` em um resultado de uma consulta.

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
select TRIM(NUMERO)
from ENDERECO
```

No `Sql Server Management` o comando é "reconhecido", ficando na coloração de um comando válido, porém retornou o seguinte erro:

> 'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Consegui resolver com o seguinte comando:

```
select RTRIM(LTRIM(NUMERO))
from ENDERECO
```

Porém precisei utilizar duas funções que ao meu ver poderia ser resolvido com apenas uma função, e o comando `trim`, será que há alguma forma de "instalar" ele, porque o `Sql Server Managemente` o colore?

Comment: Qual a versão do `SQL Server` que está utilizando?

Comment: Qual versão do sql server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Problema

O comando `TRIM` só é reconhecido a partir da versão de 2017, por isso que o seu `Sql Server Managemente` o reconhece, mas se você esta conectando a uma versão antiga do `Sql Server` você vai precisar utiliza o `RTRIM` e o `LTRIM`.

[Fonte](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

## Solução

**Versões acima do 2017**

Executando o comando nas versões acima do 2017

```
SELECT TRIM('     test    ') AS Result;
```

**Versões abaixo do 2017**

Executando o comando nas versões abaixo do 2017

```
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM('     test    ')) AS Result;
```

## Conclusão

Certamente ficou mais fácil executar esta ação na versão mais nova, utilizando apenas uma função o problema é solucionado.